# MySQL: Add columns from Database1.TableA to Database2.TableA

Tags: mysql, database

Need some help merging the changes of a former web development team.  They have created four new columns in a "Database1.TableA" for the development site.
**Is there an SQL query that will copy the structure and data from the four new columns in "Database1.TableA" into "Database2.TableA"?**

Thanks

Comment: Copy the table structure or the data ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be easily possible using the [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table-select.html) Syntax.

Comment: i'm not sure if would create the same issue i was having earlier. Because i had a similar problem trying to use phpMyAdmin to delete the Database2.Table1 and simply copy/create Database1.Table1. It would not allow me to remove Database2.Table1 because "foreign key constraint fails".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way to automatically copy the structure. The data can be updated with

```
UPDATE new_db.table n
JOIN old_db.table o on o.primary_key_col = n.primary_key_col
SET n.col1=o.col1,n.col2=o.col2,...
```

Comment: im trying to test using col1 = 'autorelist'; however, i am getting the error: #1054 - Unknown column 'n.autorelist' in 'field list'. this makes sense because 'autorelist' does not previously exist in the new table. how can overcome this?

Comment: You have to add the new columns 1-st. This will only update the data from one table to the other.

Comment: the columns now exist, but still cannot get the values to copy. this will suffice though. thank you.